# Whether the flash size of cobalt including run-time resource will keep increasing?

Tags: cobalt

For coablt 10.56829, the built out cobalt binary(QA) has about 21 MB flash size， and the content resource has about 53M flash size， totally about 74 MB, it means it needs about 74M flash size at run time, so is there a chance to reduce the flash size of cobalt? And whether it would keep a limit to avoid the flash size of cobalt which may be keeping increasing in future?

Comment: To find out about future development for a tool, ask the tool developers.

Comment: hi, dave, thank you for your suggestion, for this question, we want to know if there is any way to optimize or limit the flash size of cobalt, if the used flash size of cobalt is keeping increasing, the partion of where cobalt laid may be overflow one day.

Comment: If there are cobalt users here they can try to answer that question, I was just pointing out that only the developers can answer your second question: "And whether it will keep increasing in future?"  (But for most software the answer is "yes" :)  )

Comment: Yeath, here are some cobalt core developers may give suggestions for it with cobalt tag questions, thanks so much for your kind suggesstion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we're actively monitoring Cobalt's package size and trying to keep it as low as possible.  That said, as development occurs, it may of course fluctuate.

If you're interested in reducing your package's total size, one option to explore is to adjust the font package used with your build.  You can set this by adjusting the value of 'cobalt_font_package' in your gyp_configuration.gypi file.  See https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/build/config/base.gypi#97 for more information.